# How to include Oleacc for GetProcessHandleFromHwnd (Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am using Visual C++ express 2008 and I want to call GetProcessHandleFromHwnd. I know that I need to include Oleacc which I did by coding

```
#include <Oleacc.h>
```

and I also added Oleacc.lib in the Configuration Properties / linker / input / Additional Dependencies. I keep getting the  "error C3861: 'GetProcessHandleFromHwnd': identifier not found".

I searched on the net and it seems that I should not need to do anything else...

What I want to do is to get the process for the currently focused application. If there is another simpler way, I am open to suggestions!

Comment: It was discontinued, XP was the last OS that still had it.  Use GetWindowThreadProcessId() + OpenProcess() instead.